# Commands \tiny, etc. invalid in math mode, but not so

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

We know that `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, etc. are text font macros, and we are notified when using them in math mode:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Command \tiny invalid in math mode on input line ...

Nevertheless, as shown by the following MCE, they look like to work, at least in the `equation` environment (with the downside that the size of the tag's equation is changed as well). Interestingly, they don't work in the `equation*` environment.

Hence, the commands \tiny, etc. are invalid in math mode, but not so, isn't it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \tiny%
  e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
  \tiny%
 e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

This question arose to myself because a user wants an equation with `cases` environment to be smaller. In such a case, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`, which are usually advised in order to use a different (smaller) font inside math mode, don't work as shown by the following MCE (which, BTW, shows how to get normal-sized tags):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \tiny%
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\maketag@@@}[1]{\hbox{\m@th\normalsize\normalfont#1}}%
  \makeatother
  \begin{cases}
    e^{i\pi}+1=0
  \end{cases}
  \normalsize
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \scriptstyle%
  \begin{cases}
    e^{i\pi}+1=0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \scriptscriptstyle%
  \begin{cases}
    e^{i\pi}+1=0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The math fonts are not set up and LaTeX screams at you:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <0.7> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 7.
```

so basically nothing is working but as you chose `\tiny` and don't really want the subscripts to be impossibly small to read the fact that they are not set up at all and latex does something sort of reasonable as a fallback makes an output that looks plausible, but this is by luck not by design.

Comment: Sorry, my CE was too M: the default math fonts are indeed not set up but, with e.g. `kpfonts`, no more scream :) In such a case, is it then also by luck?

Comment: Context of my question added in the OP.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé ah but the new question about `\scriptstyle` and `cases` is completely unrelated to the latex fint size question.  That is `$\scriptstyle x \mbox{$ y $}$`   the `y`  is normal sized as the inner math list does not pick up the `\scriptstyle` setting due to the way that works at the primitive level in Tex.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé On kp fonts and is it luck, well that depends, it's a deterministic system so nothing is really down to luck. There are cases when a latex size command will work, but mostly there are cases where it will not work (or at least not do what a user expects) so it works if a primitive math display (but not if numbered) it won't work inside a group so `x+{\tiny y}`  it won't work in any sensible way inside an alignment it might not work in the first math expression depending how the math font package set up the initial fonts. ...

Comment: @DenisBitouzé So Leslie Lamport in the very earliest drafts of latex decided to make it an error rather than document where it might work. Hard to argue that was a bad decision.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using boxes, but the offset between the baseline and the center depends on the font size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x = \begin{cases} e^{i\pi}+1=0 \\  e^{i\pi}+1=0 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x = \raisebox{0.6pt}{\footnotesize $\displaystyle \begin{cases} e^{i\pi}+1=0 \\  e^{i\pi}+1=0 \end{cases} \frac{1}{2}$}
   \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works nicely, but not very handy for documents authors.

Comment: It turns out that any `\hbox` will do, not jsut saveboxes.

Answer (score 1):

`unicode-math` package's `\setmathfont` command maps glyphs to names for "every symbol and alphabetic variant" (`texdoc unicode-math`, p7 (s4)), so that suggests that changing sizes via the single point of the incoming source font itself, by using the underlying `fontspec` package's `Scale=` font option, is possible.

A quick test of scaling at factors 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 2, and 2.5 produces (100% magnification, blue is unscaled):

[image: scaling equations]

Could be an option worth exploring, perhaps.

Performance: Resetting 000s of  symbols etc (or however many) is about 5-8 seconds, so 7 such changes is about half a minute.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Pagella Math}[Colour=blue]

\newcommand\smathscale[1][1]{%
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Pagella Math}[Scale=#1]
}
\newcommand\smathscalea{\smathscale[0.5]}
\newcommand\smathscaleb{\smathscale[0.75]}
\newcommand\smathscalec{\smathscale}
\newcommand\smathscaled{\smathscale[1.25]}
\newcommand\smathscalee{\smathscale[1.5]}
\newcommand\smathscalef{\smathscale[2]}
\newcommand\smathscaleg{\smathscale[2.5]}

\newcommand\testmaths{%
\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    e^{i\pi}+1=0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}}


\begin{document}
\testmaths
\smathscalea\testmaths
\smathscaleb\testmaths
\smathscalec\testmaths
\smathscaled\testmaths
\smathscalee\testmaths
\smathscalef\testmaths
\smathscaleg\testmaths

\end{document}
```